# How to match a string unless it contains something?

Tags: regex, powershell

I have a PowerShell script that will get a list of all files within a folder and then (based on regex matches within a `Switch` statement) will move each file to a specified folder (depending on the regex match).

I'm having an issue with a particular list.  A group of files (PDF files named after their part number) that begin with "40" get moved to a specified folder.

The regex itself for just THAT is easy enough for me, the problem I am having is that, IF the file contains  `_ol`  OR  `_ol_` then it cannot be a match.

For example, the file names below should all match:

```
401234567.pdf
401234567a.pdf
401234567_a.pdf
401234567a_something.pdf
```

Those below should NOT match:

```
401234567_ol.pdf
401234567_ol_something.pdf
```

Using a `^(?i)40\w+[^_ol].pdf$` regex is the closest it seems I can get.
It will negate the `401234567_ol.pdf` as being a match; however, it accepts the `401234567_ol_something.pdf`. Does anybody know how I can negate that as being a match as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a negative look-ahead:

```
^(?i)(?!.*_ol)40\w+\.pdf$
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/rO7uN7/2)

The look-ahead `(?!.*_ol)` in the very beginning of the pattern check if later in the string we do not have `_ol`. If it is present, we have no match. Dot must be escaped to match a literal dot.

Comment: Thanks, knew an answer would be quick to come.  I did try that (the negative look-ahead idea); however, did not have the syntax right.

Comment: Could you also post that attempt so that I could comment on that?

Comment: Also, please consider accepting the answer if it worked for you.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a negative look ahead in your regex. The following regex will match any string that doesn't contains `_ol`:

```
^((?!_ol).)*$
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/nQ3uM3/1)

Note that you need to use modifier `m` (multiline) for multiline string.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use the [`-notmatch` operator](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847759.aspx) with a pattern that matches what you want to exclude:

```
Get-ChildItem 'C:\source' -Filter '*.pdf' |
  ? { $_.BaseName -notmatch '_ol(_|$)' } |
  Move-Item -Destination 'C:\destination'
```

or the `-notlike` operator (for better performance):

```
Get-ChildItem 'C:\source' -Filter '*.pdf' |
  ? { $_.BaseName -notlike '*_ol' -and $_.BaseName -notlike '*_ol_*' } |
  Move-Item -Destination 'C:\destination'
```